# how can I check what type of element row contains select or input?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have html table I run on all table rows using map function:

```
 var fieldsValuesSelection = $('tr[data-id]:not([data-id=""])').map(function () {


    // check element type here

}).get();
```

Row contains select or input element. For example:

```
<tr data-id="6">
    <td style="vertical-align: inherit;text-align:center;">
        <label for="">diameter</label></td><td style="text-align:center;"><div class="ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset">
        <input type="text" id="propFieldName" data-id="6" value="4"></div>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr data-id="7">
    <td style="vertical-align: inherit;text-align:center;">
        <label for="">state</label></td><td style="text-align:center;"><div class="ui-select">
        <div id="select-41-button" class="ui-btn ui-icon-carat-d ui-btn-icon-right ui-corner-all ui-shadow">
        <span>fixed</span>
        <select data-realvalueid="20">
            <option value="">fixed</option>
            <option value="">not fixed</option>
        </select>
        </div></div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

as you can see above first table row contains input second contains select element.

My question is how can I check inside map function what type of element row contains
    is it select or input?

Comment: `if ($(this).is('input')) { // .. input }` http://api.jquery.com/is/ , And you should apply that to each child element of $(this), in your case.

Comment: [`tagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/tagName)

Comment: Using jQuery, you can simply use  `$(this).find('input').length`  to check if input is present in current element or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find()` with `nodeName` or `type`.

**Using `nodeName`:**

```js
var fieldsValuesSelection = $('tr[data-id]:not([data-id=""])').map(function (i,el) {
  var type = $(el).find('select, input')[0].nodeName;
  console.log(type + ' at index ' + i);
}).get();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr data-id="6">
    <td style="vertical-align: inherit;text-align:center;">
        <label for="">diameter</label></td><td style="text-align:center;"><div class="ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset">
        <input type="text" id="propFieldName" data-id="6" value="4"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr data-id="7">
    <td style="vertical-align: inherit;text-align:center;">
        <label for="">state</label></td><td style="text-align:center;"><div class="ui-select">
        <div id="select-41-button" class="ui-btn ui-icon-carat-d ui-btn-icon-right ui-corner-all ui-shadow">
        <span>fixed</span>
        <select data-realvalueid="20">
            <option value="">fixed</option>
            <option value="">not fixed</option>
        </select>
        </div></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Using `type`:**

**Please Note:** For select elements, there are two possible values. `select-one` for normal select elements, and `select-multiple` when more than one value is accepted.

```js
var fieldsValuesSelection = $('tr[data-id]:not([data-id=""])').map(function (i,el) {
  var type = $(el).find('select, input')[0].type;
  console.log(type + ' at index ' + i);
}).get();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr data-id="6">
    <td style="vertical-align: inherit;text-align:center;">
        <label for="">diameter</label></td><td style="text-align:center;"><div class="ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset">
        <input type="text" id="propFieldName" data-id="6" value="4"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr data-id="7">
    <td style="vertical-align: inherit;text-align:center;">
        <label for="">state</label></td><td style="text-align:center;"><div class="ui-select">
        <div id="select-41-button" class="ui-btn ui-icon-carat-d ui-btn-icon-right ui-corner-all ui-shadow">
        <span>fixed</span>
        <select data-realvalueid="20">
            <option value="">fixed</option>
            <option value="">not fixed</option>
        </select>
        </div></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the element's `tagName` for either 'INPUT' or 'SELECT' (must be uppercase). Checkout the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/tagName).

Answer (score 0):

You want [`filter`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) not `map`

```
var fieldsValuesSelection = $('tr[data-id]:not([data-id=""])').filter(function () {
  return $('select', this).length > 0
}).get();

console.log(fieldsValuesSelection)
```